# Using Java Singleton class in Spring as prototype

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I have a class which is plain Java Singleton.

```
public class MySingleton {

    Private static instance  = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton(){}

    public static getInstance(){
       return instance;
    }
```

Now if I use this singleton class as a bean in Spring in prototype scope will Spring create multiple instance of this pure singleton class?

```
<bean id="supposedToBeSingleton" class="MySingleton" scope="prototype" />
```

Comment: Try it out, see what happens. I'd bet on an exception since Spring can't access a constructor (unless it makes it accessible, which just seems clumsy and stupid).

Comment: I know for sure Spring can access the private constructor using reflection. But question is will it create multiple instance for each call now?

Comment: Anyone *can* access private constructors using reflection, the question is *does* Spring do that when it can result in such inconsistency. Of course you can't really blame Spring in this case, but still. Why not try it and see?

Comment: Or is there something that prevents you from trying it? You say that you have that code, so wouldn't it be easier to just see how it is instead of asking here? Or do you not know how to test it?

Comment: You have code in hand, run it, and get self enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of spring is incorect thats why it is bringing errors , you should define as this

 Where by YourClassName stands for your class(parent or child class)

Answer (score 0):

Logically Spring will not use

```
         public static getInstance(){
           return instance;
         }
```

which is returning the singleton so it will return prototype using the default constructor. But to be sure you can just run the test.